# There ain't no such thing as a free tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

The [free](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/free) tag has 107 questions tagged to it - it dosen't have very much of a practical purpose (free what? Free as in beer? Free as in speech? Free hugs? Free space?), so, perhaps mercifully burninating it to a crisp may be a good idea. Its a seriously meta tag.

If we *do* end up manually editing out the tag for a natural death, we may want to organise this so we don't bulk edit (in short, no. DO NOT BULK EDIT. BAD THINGS WILL HAPPEN.)

Comment: Burn it … with extreme prejudice!! (See, I learned something :P)

Comment: I vote for Free-Beer. actually should be used in conjunction with another tag name like, "free-software"

Answer (score 3):

I've started to edit it out, though gradually - i'd like to avoid massive editfloodage if possible. I'm going at around 5-10 minute intervals per edit when i have free time, which seems alright - there were 107 questions with this tag when this was started, so it could take a while.

If the edits *do* get annoying, i'm usually on chat the same time i'm on SU, so ping me somehow and i'll try to extend the intervals, or just knock off doing these edits for the day

If anyone else is editing, I'd ask that you try not to do mass edits cause its *annoying* and this in no way is a time sensitive bit of janitorial work.

Comment: Why though? The tag has no meaning at all, it should just be silently nuked altogether. There's no point in manually going through it with 107 questions. This kind of manual work is only necessary for retags.

Comment: Is there a way to autonuke though? I'm under the impression we need to call in an ---airstrike--- dev to do it

Comment: [No strikeout in comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/134464/159624) :P But yeah, we just need to nag a dev to do it once your question has seen enough support.

Comment: You just need to read that part of the comment in a strikeout tone of voice. I'll put it off for now till there's a bit more support, and mod consensus.

Comment: @slhck autonuke might mean you'll end up with lots of [tag:untagged] questions around.

Comment: I agree with this, only I'd suggest asking more people to get involved, esp from Root Access rather than you taking it on single-handedly, which'll prolly cause to tear your hair

Comment: @Sathya Shouldn't we then just retag all the untagged ones? That'd be much faster/efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Some housekeeping things

These questions are not edited cause they either belong in webapps.se or should be deleted

Leaving them out for now for batch janitorial work

https://superuser.com/questions/24841/where-is-a-good-place-to-make-a-free-website-with-my-own-html-css

https://superuser.com/questions/24917/free-sign-up-for-my-non-profit-conference-website-with-registration-cap

https://superuser.com/questions/17812/free-blog-sites-where-the-blogs-can-if-the-template-does-validate-as-xhtml-str

https://superuser.com/questions/220065/free-software-for-learning-arabic-language